# Can I choose where nvm installs older versions?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am using a work laptop which I don't have admin access for. I need admin access to use nvm anyway, so I can get someone in IT to provide this so that I can use the command prompt as administrator. I can then use nvm to install an older verion of node so that I can switch between when I need to.

The problem I have is that nvm installs the old version onto the admin users account and this caused all sorts of issues for me, I couldn't use the npm command anywhere which stopped me from working on code. I had to delete all versions of node and install the latest version to get be able to work again.

Is it possible to choose where nvm installs the older version of node? I'm not even sure this will fix the issue for me but I want to try it anyway, I will still need admin access to switch between the 2 but if I can work on the older version that's a win.

I have looked online for the answer to my question but can't find one. Can someone please confirm?

Comment: There is something promising on [these lines](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/install.sh#L27-L33) of the install script of `nvm`'s source code, check them out.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/848

This seems to be not possible.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.